# fit_generator in keras, loading everything into memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, generator

I have original data (X_train, y_train), and I am modifying this data into something else. Original data are just images with labels. Modified data should be pairs of images for Siamese network which are high in number and it would be around 30 GB in memory. So can't run this function to create pairs on whole original data. So, I used keras fit_generator thinking it would load only that particular batch.

I ran both model.fit and also model.fit_generator on sample pairs but i observed both are using the same amount memory. So, I guess think some problem with my code in using fit_generator. Below is the relevant code. Can you guys please help me with this?

Code Below:

```
    def create_pairs(X_train, y_train):
        tr_pairs = []
        tr_y = []

        y_train = np.array(y_train)
        digit_indices = [np.where(y_train == i)[0] for i in list(set(y_train))]

        for i in range(len(digit_indices)):
            n = len(digit_indices[i])
            for j in range(n):
                random_index = digit_indices[i][j]
                anchor_image = X_train[random_index]
                anchor_label = y_train[random_index]
                anchor_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(y_train) if x == anchor_label]
                negate_indices = list(set(list(range(0,len(X_train)))) - set(anchor_indices))
                for k in range(j+1,n):
                    support_index = digit_indices[i][k]
                    support_image = X_train[support_index]
                    tr_pairs += [[anchor_image,support_image]]

                    negate_index = random.choice(negate_indices)
                    negate_image = X_train[negate_index]
                    tr_pairs += [[anchor_image,negate_image]]

                    tr_y += [1,0]


        return np.array(tr_pairs),np.array(tr_y) 



    def myGenerator():
        tr_pairs, tr_y = create_pairs(X_train, y_train)
        while 1:
            for i in range(110): # 1875 * 32 = 60000 -> # of training samples
                if i%125==0:
                    print("i = " + str(i))
                yield [tr_pairs[i*32:(i+1)*32][:, 0], tr_pairs[i*32:(i+1)*32][:, 1]], tr_y[i*32:(i+1)*32]




    model.fit_generator(myGenerator(), steps_per_epoch=110, epochs=2,
                  verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_data=([te_pairs[:, 0], te_pairs[:, 1]], te_y), validation_steps=None, class_weight=None,
                  max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0)
```

Comment: What is `X_train` and `y_train`? If they are 30GB and and does not fit into the memory, how did you load them and use them in this line: `tr_pairs, tr_y = create_pairs(X_train, y_train)`?

Comment: (X_train, y_train) is not 20 GB, its just a small dataset. Create_pairs is a function which can be controlled to have number of combination from X_train and y_train. I can create dataset ranging from 20GB to 1GB using this function. I loaded that 1GB data.

Comment: I see. So you need to make the `create_pairs` itself a generator. I wanted to show you how to do this, but `create_pairs` seems a bit complicated to me and I couldn't figure out the best way to do it. However, the idea is the same with the way you have written `myGenerator`. You should somehow modify `create_pairs` in such a way that it can generate one batch of data at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`myGenerator` returns a generator.

However you should notice that `create_pairs` is loading the full dataset into memory. When you call `tr_pairs, tr_y = create_pairs(X_train, y_train)` the dataset is loaded, so the memory resources are being used.

`myGenerator` simply traverses a structure that is already in memory.

The solution would be to make `create_pairs` a generator itself.

If the data is a numpy array I can suggest using `h5` files to read chuncks of data from disk.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage

Comment: thanks for the help, how can we make create_pairs itself as generator?